# Number of squares in a $n×n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics

You are told to choose 4 squares from a $n×n$ square grid such that the quadrilateral formed by joining the centers of those squares is a square. Find the number of ways to do so.

I tried to solve by forming a recursion. But I could not figure out the recursion formula.

Any help will be appreciated...

Also, how can this be generalised to $m×n$ grid?

Comment: Values for small values of $n$? Maybe find the values in the $n \times n$ case for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and enter those values into www.oeis.org and see what you get? Then see how you can generalize to an $m \times n$ grid.

Comment: It is always a good idea to add intermediate questions : 

You are told to choose 4 squares from a $n \times n$  square grid such that the quadrilateral formed by joining the centers of those squares is a square with size $k$ ; Find the number of ways to do so.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{n^4-n^2}{12}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let the centers of the squares of the grid be located at integer coordinates $(x,y)$ for $x,y\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Now, assume we have four points $(x_i,y_i)$ that form a square. Let the **enclosing box** be defined by $x_{\min}=\min x_i$, $x_{\max}=\max x_i$,  $y_{\min}=\min y_i$, and $y_{\max}=\max y_i$. The **size of the enclosing box** is $k=x_{\max}-x_{\min}=y_{\max}-y_{\min}$.

Given an enclosing box of size $k$ defined by $x_\min<x_\max, y_\min<y_\max$ with $k=x_{\max}-x_{\min}=y_{\max}-y_{\min}$, four points forming a square which is enclosed by this box can be picked in exactly $k$ different ways as it is uniquely determined by the one point which has $x_i=x_\min$, $y_i\in\{y_\min,\ldots,y_\max-1\}$.

In an $n\times n$ grid, an enclosing box of size $k$ must have $0\le x_\min,y_\min<n-k$, and these can be selected in $(n-k)^2$ different ways.

Thus, you can pick size $k$ enclosing boxes in $(n-k)^2$ different ways for $k<n$, and a four point square with this enclosing box in $k$ different ways, which makes the total number of ways to pick a four point square in
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)^2\cdot k$ different ways.

For a $n\times m$ grid with $n\le m$, the number of four point squares becomes $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)(m-k)k$